# Access Apache VirtualHost from localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, nat, namevirtualhost

I have a DirectAdmin setup with Apache on a server which is behind NAT.

Everything is working correctly when accessing a VirtualHost from outside the machine (either through the Internet and the Intranet) but I'm having problems when accessing the very same VirtualHost from the localhost (i.e. by using curl mywebsite.com inside the server).

Relevant network devices:

```
eth0   : IP Address inside the NAT
eth0:0 : IP Address outside the NAT (i.e. public IP Address)
eth1   : LAN IP Address
lo     : Loopback
```

Below is the relevant httpd configuration:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

When using a wildcarded `NameVirtualHost`one would expect a request with the `Host: mydomain.com` directive set in the request header (which `curl` does) to be served by the `VirtualHost` directive. Although, when I `curl mydomain.com` from inside the server, Apache fallback to the `DocumentRoot` not allowing me to access the `VirualHost` host.

The only way I got it to work was to edit `/etc/hosts` and define the IP inside the NAT for `mydomain.com`.

Another piece of information that may be useful:

I ran `<?php print_r($_SERVER); ?>` on a test page both from inside and outside the server to check the values for `SERVER_IP` and when I `curl` from a remote machine I get the IP address inside the NAT, but when I `curl` from inside the server I get the public IP address.

The domain resolves to the very same IP address on both ends (inside and outside the server).

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://xip.io to define a temporary domain for your virtual host using your computer's IP address.

Simple and easy ;)

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer, nor does your link work

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look into this post from me to see if it is relevant

[reaching an apache reverse proxy virtualhost from localhost behind a NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/1100676/reaching-an-apache-reverse-proxy-virtualhost-from-localhost-behind-a-nat)